# Get Selected Item in ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

OK, so I have a ComboBox filled with ComboBoxItem which contain Rectangular Content which have a Fill field:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" Width="100">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
        <ComboBoxItem.Content>
            <Rectangle Fill="#8BC34A" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Fill="#7CB342" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Fill="#689F38" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Fill="#558B2F" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Fill="#33691E" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And I need to get a Brush from a Rectangle's Fill (or at least a string value of Fill). So I tried this:

```
var comboBoxItem = comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex] as ComboBoxItem;
var cmb = comboBoxItem.Content as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle;
```

And then get Fill via cmd.Fill, but i get a null exception.

So how can I get it? I need it to color something from a chosen value of ComboBox. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get *null* in comboboxitem's content. However, should work if you do it like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" Width="100">
    <Rectangle Fill="#8BC34A" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#7CB342" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#689F38" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#558B2F" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#33691E" Width="50" Height="50"/>
</ComboBox>
```

then you can just simply cast selected item to *Rectangle*:

```
var selectedRectangle = comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex] as Rectangle;
var selectedRectangle = comboBox.SelectedItem as Rectangle;
```

Note that usually *ComboBox* works with *ItemsSource* and *ItemTemplate*, in that case your code can look like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" Width="100">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToBrushConverter}}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>FF8BC34A</x:String>
    <x:String>FF7CB342</x:String>
    <x:String>FF689F38</x:String>
    <x:String>FF558B2F</x:String>
</ComboBox>
```

and the converter:

```
public class StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string color = (string)value;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < color.Length; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = byte.Parse(color.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

In that case your selected item will be a *string*. For your scenario the first method may be easier, but for more complicated scenarios this will be much better, note also that in that case you can easily bind *ComboBox* to collection of string with colors.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much! The first thing helped me! I didn't know that you can fill ComboBox like this. Once again thanks!

Comment: And one more question, how can I make one of the Rectangle checked by default?

Comment: @stroibot If you take a look at my combobox, then you will see that I've set property `SelectedIndex="0"`.